# How to fold verbatim text (not code) in R bookdown?

Tags: r-markdown, folding, bookdown, verbatim

In my document, I want to show some info, using ``` block, such as:

````
```
bruin@c7 ~ $ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
bruin@c7 ~ $
```
````

For large output chunks, I want to fold them. How to do that? Searching the web it seems all related topics are about *code* folding, but what I want to fold is not any type of code, just simple text...

Thanks!

Comment: Not implemented: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/664

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a very easy way to implement the following yourself:

[image]

You can find all the code you need in the following reproducible RMD document:

````
---
title: "Hide Verbatim Blocks"
author: "Martin Schmelzer"
date: "June 22, 2018"
output: html_document
---

<style>
.fold-btn { float: right; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fold").prepend("<button class=\"fold-btn\">Unfold</button>");
  $(".fold").children("code").toggle();
  $(".fold-btn").on("click", function() {
    if($(this).text() === "Fold") {
      $(this).text("Unfold");
    } else {
      $(this).text("Fold");
    }
    $(this).next("code").toggle("linear");
  })
});
</script>

# Rmd file

```{fold}
bruin@c7 ~ $ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
bruin@c7 ~ $
```
````

In the JS part we simply add a button to every chunk that is marked with the class `fold`. Afterwards we add the `onClick` event to all those buttons. When a button is clicked, its text should toggle between *Fold* and *Unfold*. And the corresponding code container should toggle its visibility state as well. Every chunk marked with `fold` is folded when the document is opened.
How you style the button using CSS is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I had a quick test in my existing project, it does not work, don't know why... Let me create a minimum project and try it again. Thanks again.

Comment: Update all packages. Post your YAML options or a minimum reproducible document that has the same characteristics.

Comment: It works now. I was using "bookdown::gitbook" output, after I change to "bookdown::html_document2", it works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it also works for gitbook, after several tests. I put your script into a "fold.js" file, and for gitbook output, add "includes: in_header: fold.js"; also put the ".fold-btn {float: right;}" into my existing css file. It just works as I wanted. Many thanks!

Comment: @bruin Do you know if it's possible to fold all chunks by default? thanks!