# How to fold printed output in R-Markdown file?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to make text output foldable in my HMTL-R markdown file. So when using print(something) the printed output is hidden by default but viewable after pressing a button.

There is the option to show/hide code in the R Markdown file

```
output: 
 html_document:
   code_folding: hide
```

But this does not affect printed output.

There is already a question to make verbatim text foldable (
[How to fold verbatim text (not code) in R bookdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080226/how-to-fold-verbatim-text-not-code-in-r-bookdown))
But inserting inline R code like this

````
```{fold}
`r 2 + 2`
```
````

does not work out.

Comment: Here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755037/how-to-add-code-folding-to-output-chunks-in-rmarkdown-html-documents

Comment: Thanks, I missed that question